# Python 3: importing modules - name is not defined error

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror, nameerror

I'm following Python tutorial which explain modules. As far as I understood, its piece of code in another file which can be executed in current file.

I have file converter.py:

```
def lbs_to_kg(weight):
    return weight * 0.45


def kg_to_lbs(weight):
    return weight / 0.45
```

and i want to use it in my app4.py:

```
import converter

print(converter.lbs_to_kg(200))
```

I'm doing exactly as in video, and when executing a file got message:`AttributeError: module 'converter' has no attribute 'lbs_to_kg'`

Both files are in the same directory.
Why it shows me there's no attribute, how to fix it?

Tried `import converter` and have AttributeError as above

Found another video which explain modules more deeply and tried:

```
from converter import *

print(converter.lbs_to_kg(200))
```

To import all from converter.py

But then i have: `NameError: name 'converter' is not defined` i think i'm closer to result

Comment: When you do `import converter` and then `print(converter.__file__)`, is the output the file you think it is, or a different file?

Comment: Its show me converter.py file, looks like its correctly imported

Comment: "*As far as I understood, its piece of code in another file which can be executed in current file.*"  ..... **this is incorrect**.  it is the other module. The code inside the module are the methods and attributes of the module.

Answer (score 1):

CHECK EDIT
Ok i've got something.

this is working:

```
import converter
from converter import kg_to_lbs

print(converter.lbs_to_kg(100))
```

But it looks completely different than in tutorials.

When I change

```
print(converter.lbs_to_kg(100))
```

to

```
print(converter.kg_to_lbs(100))
```

Its working correctly, but can someone explain me how?

I don't understand it. Imported only function kg_to_lbs, but even when I changed lbs_to_kg its still working.

I want to understand it :)

EDIT: I managed to have this:

```
import converter
from converter import *

print(converter.lbs_to_kg(100))
```

It's look pretty clean. But can somebody tell me why i had to do

```
import converter
from converter import *
```

while in few tutorials they had only first line and it worked properly?